# New Laravel Routes not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, xampp

I have a problem, new routes in laravel are not working, url shows the correct route but almost as if it does not get to my routes web file just returns **page not found** every time.

I have tried:
using **named route**,
moving function to **different controller**,
clearing **route cache**,
clearing **app cache**,
**dump-auto load**,
made sure that **AllowOverride** is set to **All**,

Web.php:

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Courses
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::get('/courses', 'CourseController@index');
Route::get('/courses/create', 'CourseController@create');
Route::get('/courses/{course}', 'CourseController@show');
Route::get('/courses/{course}/edit', 'CourseController@edit');
Route::post('/courses', 'CourseController@store');
Route::patch('/courses/{course}', 'CourseController@update');
Route::delete('/courses/{course}', 'CourseController@destroy')->name('course-delete');

Route::get('/courses/statistics', 'CourseController@statistics');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| First Aid
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::get('/section/{section}', 'SectionController@show');


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| First Aid
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::get('/progress', 'UserProgressController@index');
Route::get('/progress/create', 'UserProgressController@create');
Route::get('/progress/{section}', 'UserProgressController@show');
Route::get('/progress/formativeresults', 'UserProgressController@formativeresults');
//Route::get('/progress/coursestatistics', 'UserProgressController@coursestatistics');
//Route::get('/progress/{progress}/edit', 'UserProgressController@edit');
Route::post('/progress', 'UserProgressController@store');
//Route::patch('/progress/{progress}', 'UserProgressController@update');
//Route::delete('/progress/{progress}', 'UserProgressController@destroy')->name('progress-delete');
```

Controller:

```
public function statistics()
    {
        dd('Test');
       return view('coursestatistics');
    }
```

View file name:
**coursestatistics.blade.php** file structure views/coursestatistics

Link to page:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/courses/statistics">
   {{ __('Statistics') }}
</a>
```

Can anyone tell me what might be causing route not to work?

Comment: Show the complete route file content, one of your route's might be overriding this one

Comment: Question updated with complete route file

Comment: Ok thanks, much better

Comment: Fellow South African :P you spelled software wrong on your profile :D

Comment: Haha well spotted thank you @emotality will be sure to fix that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try placing

```
Route::get('/courses/statistics', 'CourseController@statistics');
```

below this particular line of route code

```
Route::get('/courses/create', 'CourseController@create');
```

The general rule of laravel routing is to place specific routes before wildcard routes that are related. Link [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/order-of-routes-in-webphp?page=1)

Comment: That worked for me thanks!, might have found another issue with Route::get('/progress/{section}', 'UserProgressController@show'); possibly because the wildcard is not named the progress as well causing issues with any routes below this one.

Comment: Ahh nice catch! :D

Comment: @JellyBean Were you able to fix the progress route too?

Comment: yes just name the wild card the same as the route all is well thank you

Comment: Update on my comment about the wild card, its not that it should be named the same as the route, it could be named anything as long as the wild card used is also used in the controller e.g. public function store(Model $wildcard){ ... }

Answer (score 22):

I had same issue, Did all those magic with configs and nothing..
Solution: run: **php artisan route:clear**

Answer (score 2):

If issue remains same After cache clear or  laravel routing rule, use 'composer dump-autoload'

Answer (score 0):

If in your controller you have Model::findorFail($id) and an object with that ID does not exist, it can also lead to this error (in Laravel 6)